# adding and grouping by using a specific criteria with where clause

Tags: sql-server

I know it's very basic but since I am new to this, I wanted to get a doubt cleared. I have to get the sum of a particular column and then group that column by two criteria.
The code is tried is :

```
    Select sum (column_name) 
    from table_name 
    group by column_name 
    where columb_name = 1 or column_name = 36;
```

I always get syntax error near where. I am using MS Server 2014.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Select SUM(column_name) from table_name where columb_name = 1 or column_name = 36 group by column_name

"Where" clause must be placed before "group by" clause

Answer (score 0):

You should place where clause before group by like below :

```
 Select sum (column_name) 
    from table_name 
    where columb_name = 1 or column_name = 36 
    group by column_name ;
```